# How to declare dynamic array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, dynamic-arrays

I am working on `silverligth5` (my previous experience is c++)and i have to create a dynamic array whose size is decided dynamically.

Until i have everything static and it's like this:

```
string[] position = new string[20]; //it must be dynamic I don't want to fix it to 20
 for (int i = 0; i < pv.Root.Parameter.Count; i++) 
 {
    if (name == pv.Root.Parameter[i].Name) 
    {
        position[i] = name;
    }
 }
```

As it can be seen that the way i do will have size `20` only and i want it to be only of the same length as  `pv.Root.Parameter.Count`.

How to achieve this ?

EDIT/ the problem when i try to achieve it through list :  I have problem  at this line :

```
if (pv.Root.Parameter[loopCount].Name == position[loopCount])
{ 
   rowGrid.Opacity=0.3;
}
```

Because surely it will not work `position[loopCount]` because position is a List and cannot be indexed like this. How to index it ?

Comment: Any reason you can't work with a generic list?

Comment: As others have said: Embrace the `List<T>`. An array is so 70's

Comment: The code `pv.Root.Parameter[loopCount].Name == position[loopCount]` looks dubious since `position` should be shorter than `pv.Root.Parameter` so `position[loopCount]` can well throw `IndexOutOfRange`

Answer (score 7):

pass the `pv.Root.Parameter.Count` instead of `20` as the array length.

```
string[] position = new string[pv.Root.Parameter.Count];
```

Or use a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you don't want a fixed size.

Comment: I have a problem in your code because when i use List to do this, after doing that i also have to do this if (pv.Root.Parameter[loopCount].Name == position[loopCount]) && pv.Root.Parameter[loopCount].Component.Attributes.Value == 1) { rowGrid.Opacity=0.3; } AND THIS THING SUELY WILL CREATE PROBLEM "position[loopCount]" in this if() condition. How tyo solve this problem

Comment: who says you can't use the indexer with List ? did you even try?

Comment: The 'requirements' -- the desired result -- are clear as mud.  What is the purpose of the `position` array/list?  Does the `position` array/list need to be the same length as `pv.Root.Parameter`?  If so (`position` must be same length a `pv.Root.Parameter`), and based on the very first code snippet, it will be an array/list of Length/Count pv.Root.Parameter.Count, with 0 - pv.Root.Parameter.Count non-null entries.  Then, in your edited code:  `if(position[loopCount] != null && pv.Root.Parameter[loopCount].Name == position[loopCount]) { ... }`

Comment: Sorry, the if statement would be something like:
`if( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(position[loopCount]) && pv.Root.Parameter[loopCount].Name == position[loopCount]) { ... }`

Comment: Another option, if `position` doesn't need to be same size as pv.Root.Parameter.Count.    `Dictionary<int,string> position = ....;  if (name == pv.Root.Parameter[i].Name) {   positions.Add(i, name); }`  To look up based on loopCount:  `if   (pv.Root.Parameter[loopCount].Name == position[loopCount]) { ... }`

Comment: Ack, need to make sure there is an entry for loopCount:  if (position.ContainsKey(loopCount) && /* test for name */ ...)

Answer (score 4):

You probably want an "infinite" array.
Use a `List` instead of an array.

In your case:

```
List<string> positions = new List<string>();
 for (int i = 0; i < pv.Root.Parameter.Count; i++) 
 {
    if (name == pv.Root.Parameter[i].Name) 
    {
        positions.Add(name); //To get an element use positions.ElementAt(<index>)
    }
 }
```

Or if you need an array of n elements use:

```
string[] position = new string[pv.Root.Parameter.Count]];
```

Comment: I have a problem in your code because when i use List to do this, after doing that i also have to do this if (pv.Root.Parameter[loopCount].Name == position[loopCount] && pv.Root.Parameter[loopCount].Component.Attributes.Value == 1)
                { 
                 rowGrid.Opacity=0.3;
                } AND THIS THING SUELY WILL CREATE PROBLEM "position[loopCount]" in this if() condition. How tyo solve this problem

Comment: As I wrote in the comment you just need to replace position[index] with position.ElementAt(index)

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt' and no extension method 'ElementAt' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) .I AM USING SILVERLIGHT

Comment: Did you import System.Collections and System.Collections.Generic?

Comment: And by the way what are passing as parameter in ElementAt? Because from the error it seams that you are passing a list. You should pass an integer. For example: position.ElementAt(1) (1 is for example)!

Answer (score 4):

You can try using *Linq*:

```
String[] position = pv.Root.Parameter
  .Where(item => name == item.Name)
  .Select(item => item.Name)
  .ToArray();
```

Or if you want `List<T>` and not array

```
List<String> position = pv.Root.Parameter
  .Where(item => name == item.Name)
  .Select(item => item.Name)
  .ToList();
```